# How to split a string and see if its the last entry in the string?

Tags: java, string, split

I have a string and would like to split every sub string and add it to a stack, except for the last sub string to be added to a list.

```
String keysFromString = One|Two|Three;      
Stack<String> s = new Stack<String>();
List <String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>(); 

  if (keysFromString .contains("|")) {
        String[] keys = keysFromString .split("|");
     for (String key : keys) {
             s.add(key)
        }
    }
```

Here I want One, Two in stack and Three in list, but I am not sure as how to identify and add the last entry to list as the given string may contain variable number of sub strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String keysFromString = "One|Two|Three";      
Stack<String> s = new Stack<String>();
List <String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>(); 

if (keysFromString .contains("|")) 
{
    String[] keys = keysFromString .split("|");
    //grab all but the last string in keys and add it to stack (s)
    for (int i = 0; i < keys.length - 1; i++) 
    {
         s.add(keys[i])
    }
    //add the last string from the split method to the stringList
    stringList.add(keys[keys.length - 1]);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `stringList.add(s.pop());` after your loop.

Comment: That would still not differentiate the last sub string from the rest.

Comment: The last sub string will be on top of your stack.

Comment: The question was how to add all substrings to the stack except the last, not to add them all then remove the last one.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your current loop:

```
for (String key : keys) {
         s.add(key)
    }
```

with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < keys.length - 1; i++) {
         s.add(keys[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

using :

```
for (int i= 0; i<keys.length -1; i++) {
             s.add(keys[i]);
        }
```

you will not add the last element in the array

using `keys.length` , you will get the length of the array which is a property. you can use this to iterate over the array, excluding the last item :`i<keys.length - 1` . This cannot be done using the `for (String key : keys)` technique.

P.S. `keys.length()` does not exist as length is a property not a method

Comment: could you please differentiate 
String[] keys ;
keys.length 
vs
key.length(); where key is an entry inside keys

Comment: thanks for your explanation! But Ryan Zink has more detailed example so upvoting it.